# The validation that i have used is not letting me move to the next tab on my screen if its left empty

Tags: jquery

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('balaashjquery'); ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function(){
    $('#name').blur(function(){
      $nameval = $('#name').val();
      if($nameval ==""){
       alert('Name field should not be empty');
      }
    });


    $('#address').blur(function(){
      $addressval = $('#address').val();
      if($addressval ==""){
       alert('address field should not be empty');
      }
    });
          });

           </script>
          <?php echo $this->Form->create('Advertiser',
 array('controller' =>'advertisers', 'action' => 'add'));
         echo $this->Form->input('name', array('id'=>'name'));
  echo $this->Form->input('address', array('id'=>'address'));
   echo $this->Form->end('Save Advertiser');
 ?>
```

this is the code i have used ...if i leave in a field empty the validation alert box is being displayed but its not letting me move into the next tab in the screen if fields are left empty.
i actually needed a focus on the first field that is left empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use passive validation for the form fields (like add an error class to your fields) and then only do aggressive notification when the form is submitted or before you do an ajax request to submit the data.

Something like this:

```
function passive(e){
    // change the field
    $(e.target).toggleClass("ui-error",$(e.target).val() === "")
    // apply changes to the labels
    $(e.target).prev('label').toggleClass(...)
}
function aggressive(e){
    // find errors
    // alert errors
    // if errors return false
}
$("#loginForm").submit(aggressive);
$("[required]").blur(passive);
```

Even better, a validation plugin like jquery.validate allows you to create simple rules and provide localized error messages.

http://jsfiddle.net/hmEDm/

Finally, if you use a framework like angularjs there are alot of really nifty validation related things you can do right in the HTML markup.

fwiw, you should put `var` before your variable declarations (`var $nameval`, `var $addressval`) to keep the global scope clean.